# Best way to Backup project

Tags: android, eclipse, backup

Hey guys simple question here. Whats the best way to back up an android project? I use eclipse. I'm fairly new and not sure what I need to back it up. Do I need just the project or do I need the meta data also? Thanks guys

Comment: Back up a little. "Do I need just the project"?? I think you accidentally a word there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly you want to make a backup of your project? If you've never used version control before, now would be a great time to start! Version control will not only provide you with what you're looking for but many other great features. There's plenty of different SCM's available for you to choose froml; Git, SVN, Mercurial and so on.

Otherwise if all you want is to copy the project to another location, open your eclipse workspace folder (the directory you defined when you first started eclipse) and copy the project directory from there. Or do as MarchingHome suggests.

Comment: This is what I tried to suggest, but you explained it a bit more clear :) Thanks. And indeed, version control is very nice!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I meant the entire project im working on.. for example if my hard drive crashed.. id install eclipse on a new computer and be able to load my project again

Comment: Sigh. The pitfalls of typing on a mobile. My previous comment if I could edit it to fix it would say the following: No problem :-) Backing up your workspace or projects periodically is one way to go (or writing a script to do it). But version control system can do a much better job of this and provide other benefits. In any case good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I always directly copy the entire folder of the project in the eclipse workspace.
You can import that later in eclipse via File --> Import --> General --> Existing project into workspace.
You can there select the folder and everything will be restored.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you work alone and on always the same machine, you can simply backup the entire project folder with the help of a version control system like [git](http://git-scm.com/). This will help you keep track of all the changes you make and lets you undo any code changes. You can use [github](https://github.com/) as a reliable remove service. If you aren't familiar with it yet, then it might take some reading to get into, but afterwards you life will be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You need the metadata.  There are a few files in the top level project directory when you use eclipse: .cproject (this might only be if you use CDT plugin), .project and sometimes a .settings directory.  Basically, you need all the dot files/dirs.  You can just zip up the directory and that should be enough.

That said, if you try and open that project and the paths have changed, you'll probably get errors.  Same for if you're missing vital plugins used by your project.

What you should be doing is using some sort of revision control.  Try git or mercurial.  Eclipse has plugins for them as well.